# PHP Syntax Error Nav Menu

Tags: php, html, css

Okay I got this code!!

```
<td class='ActiveMainMenu' nowrap valign='top'>
```

Its a normal TD i use for the nav menu and it works well.

http://prntscr.com/8mzqbw as it shows here, the activemainmenu is the highlighted tab anyway I want it to be more dynamic in php so I made.

```
<td <?php if($page=="Home"){echo 'class="ActiveMainMenu"';}else{echo'class="MainMenu"';} ?> nowrap valign="top" >
```

But that one works in the Homepage "ActiveMainMenu" but the "else statement" isn't working it gives me an errors says Undefined Variable.

-Thanks

Comment: Could it be the missing space between echo and 'class=

Comment: What variable is undefined? `$page`?

Comment: and the undefiend is really weird
http://prntscr.com/8mzugz

Comment: Well yeah @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable I forgot to $page the second page so it couldn't do the "else function" but the first page works fine

Thanks bro <3